# Trouble adding item with PUT to dynamodb table: node.js aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am attempting to add an item to an existing dynamodb table using a PUT request. I have tried several variations of the code including using the .put as well as the .putItem functions. When I hard-code the url into the brower I get the following error:

```
Cannot GET /add-student?student_id=5&name=carl
```

When I cut the exact url which gave me this error and paste it into an api testing app, Postman, it works perfectly. I am well aware that the error says that I attempted a GET request, but I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Here's my code.

```
app.put('/add-student', function (req, res) {
    var params = {
        TableName : "student",

        Item:{
            "student_id"    : {"N": req.query.student_id},
            "name"          : {"S": req.query.name}
        }
    }
    dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err); 
        else 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
    }); 
});
```

What might be causing this to be interpreted as a get request? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when an URL is hit from the browser, the request will be send as HTTP GET request. You can't send other than GET request from browser directly without using plugins or tools.

This is the main reason for using tools like POSTMAN or any other plugins like Firefox plugins to test the REST services that works on different HTTP methods like POST, PUT etc.

1) I think when you hit the URL from POSTMAN, you would have selected the PUT method.

2) If you select the GET method in POSTMAN, you will get the same error.

See the screenshot below. Get request send from POSTMAN throws the same error.

**GET request from POSTMAN:-**

[image: GET request from POSTMAN]

**PUT request from POSTMAN:-**

[image: PUT request from POSTMAN]

**Request send from browser:-**

[image: Request send from browser]

**My code is same as yours expect table name:-**

```
app.put('/add-movie', function (req, res) {
    var params = {
        TableName:"Movies",
        Item:{
            "yearkey": {"N" : req.query.yearkey},
            "title": {"S" : req.query.title}

        }    
    };
    dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send("Put is failed...");
        }
        else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            res.send("Put is successful...");
        }

    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You have saved me more time than you might ever know. I have one additional question to ask though. If a requirement for my assignment is to write a python script to test the PUT function, how would I do that? I was attempting to just prompt a browser with the urls inserted, but that obviously won't work.

Comment: Python should have some REST api client libraries. In Java, there is spring rest client like resttemplate class. Another alternate option would be to use CURL command line interface to invoke rest service.